# Запятая перед "как": "Недорогой(,) как для электроприбора"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

Такая фраза: "Недорогой(,) как для электроприбора". Что-то я засомневался: нужна тут запятая или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложение нужно писать полностью.
(Футляр был)недорогой, как для электроприбора.
...был недорогой как для прибора, так и ...

Запятая перед "как" НЕ ставится: 
1.в устоявшихся сравнениях - белый как снег, упал как сноп, отвечать как попало и т.п.

1. если предложение имеет значение "в качестве" - Лев Толстой как художник гениален (в качестве художника). Но выделяется запятой, если есть значение причины - Иванов, как гениальный художник, пользуется заслуженной славой (так как он гениальный художник)
2. перед как...так и, когда соединяются однородные члены предложения - (на форуме бывают как профессионалы, так и любители)
3. когда входит в сказуемое или примыкает к нему : пруд как сталь

Ваш случай под это вроде бы не подходит, поэтому запятая скорее всего нужна